# Is the right way use Twilio for verifying mobile phone numbers?

Tags: twilio

I want to verify mobile phone numbers. The mobile phone numbers can be from anywhere, I mean any country. My idea is to send an sms with a code, and then ask for that code.

I am not sure if Twilio is a correct choice for doing that, because I do not understand if with a phone number from Twilio I am able to send messages around the world. I am also not sure about the costs of sending messages.

Is Twilio right for this or should I look for another service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're totally on the right track. With a Twilio number you can send SMS messages to over 200 countries, and get local numbers in over 40 countries. Have a look at [this FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/which-countries-does-twilio-have-phone-numbers-in-and-what-are-their-capabilities) for more information.

Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2010/05/simple-phone-verification-with-twilio-php-mysql-and-jquery.html) where we show you how to use Twilio to verify phone numbers on the way you asked.

You will find pricing information in [this page](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing), and it will vary slightly from country to country.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you @MarcosPlacona I just bought a number, and have started testing and is working.

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to come back and ask any more questions you may have in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can also test other similar verification service.

www.foneverify.com is one such service providing verification across the globe.

You can try our services by signing up for free.

Disclosure: I am the product manager of foneverify.

Thanks,
Shivam